# Biometrics prompt works with API 21+ but API 19 shows error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-biometric-prompt

So I have app lock on my app that uses the devices lock method - I use Biometrics 1.0.1 which support all android versions, however on KitKat when I press unlock, it shows tihs toast:

> authentication error: This device does not have a fingerprint sensor.

Even though I use .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true) which should use devices PIN or pattern if no fingerprint is available.

keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure returns true

```
promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
            .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
            .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
            .build()

        // Prompt appears when user clicks "Unlock".
        val biometricLoginButton = unlock_button
        biometricLoginButton.setOnClickListener {
            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`setDeviceCredentialAllowed()`** method only supports Api 21+

Because this api use internally `KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(CharSequence, CharSequence)` 
This method added on `API 21` and deprecated on `API 29` [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

From the [Api docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder.html#setDeviceCredentialAllowed(boolean))

> On versions P and below, once the device credential prompt is shown, BiometricPrompt.cancelAuthentication() will not work, since the library internally launches KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(CharSequence, CharSequence), which does not have a public API for cancellation.

Comment: So does that mean below API 21 BiometricPrompt has no form of backwards-compatibility?